# Hybrid app cant run on Samsung Galaxy 5 or 6

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, samsung-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid app on the play store currently (The Stylista) which runs perfectly across different platforms until its loaded on a Samsung Galaxy 5 or 6..

The app opens to a white screen with my loading gif just spinning and get no further - is there something I am missing? Code should be added?

I have been doing research and see that it is a permission issue..

[White screen and loading gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfT26.png)

Comment: Assuming you are using a webview enable debugging on the app and plug it in to a pc to see whats going on  -- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging -- https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews

Comment: @Tasos I have done extensive debugging, I don't have the devices in question so debugging the behavior on them cant take place unfortunately

Comment: well from the pic it seems that the user doesnt have an internet connection or the 4g data is not on  -- http://d38v16rqg5mb6e.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Galaxy-S5-WiFi-Disconnecting.png -- as the person to connect to a wifi conecttion and try again

Comment: That's definitely not the issue, I have just asked them to turn the phone off and back on and still the same issue. The main screen will not load for some bizarre reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was adding this snippet to the config file:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
  <application android:debuggable="true" />
</gap:config-file>
```

Then I was able to debug in the browser - ALSO with the new android versions, when testing the connection to Cordova, it was not returning the Connection variable thus failing as it was undefined. You can change the code to read:

```
function getData(tableName, data, onSuccess) {
if (navigator && navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type) {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    if (navigator.connection.type == 'none') {
        showMessage("You don't appear to be connected to the internet. Please check your connection.");

        return;
    }
}
```

Instead of the default:

```
function getData(tableName, data, onSuccess) {
if (navigator && navigator.connection && navigator.connection.type) {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
    if (networkState == Connection.NONE) {
        showMessage("You don't appear to be connected to the internet. Please check your connection.");

        return;
    }
}
```

This will allow your hybrid app to work again :)